# How remove content model if the same button is pushed multiple times or prevent click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am developing an application with Backbone.js. If I have a button and push it, a module of content is added (view and model). If I push other button, the content is removed (view and model). If I push repeatedly the button to add, the view of the content is showed and rewrite, but the previous model are not removed. How can I remove content model if the same button to add is pushed multiple times?

```
        var tabsContents = Backbone.View.extend({
el: "body", 
events: {
    "click .addAll": "addContentAll"    
},
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this); 
    this.model = new ContentCollection();
    this.model.on("add", this.contentAdded);
    this.model.on("remove", this.contentRemoved);
},          
addContentAll: function(event) {
            this.model.add({name: "all"});          
contentAdded: function(content) {
    if (content.view == null) {
        var template_name;              
        switch(content.get("name")){        
            case 'all': template_name = 'home'; break;  
        }                                       
        content.view = new ContentView({model: content,template: $.trim($("[data-template-name='"+ template_name +"'] div").html() || "Template not found!")});
        $(".box2").empty();             this.$el.find(".content").find("div.box").append(content.view.render().el);                                                 
    }       
},  
contentRemoved: function(content) {
    if (content.view != null) { 
        content.view.remove();              
    }
    content.clear();  //Clear the properties of the model               
}   
});
var ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    template: null,
    events: {
          "click .Close": "removeView"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.template = this.options.template; 
    },
    render: function() {        
        this.$el.html(Mustache.render(this.template, this.model.toJSON())); 
        return this; 
    },
    removeView: function() {
        this.model.collection.remove(this.model); //Remove the model of the coll
        }
});     
var tabsview = new tabsContents();
```

Nor do I know how to delete a model clicking a button to add another model

Comment: How about you prevent it from being added multiple times instead?

Comment: @Shmiddty. Thanks for response. How can I do it?